# How to Implement Values for New Registered User Based On Their Score?

Tags: java, mysql

What I'm trying to code for my advanced software project is the program filling random integer values depending on the value of the user's overall score into my SQL database once a user has registered an account. I'm having trouble on how to generate these values and put them into my database.

I've tried to give one of the values a random number within a certain range, but Java Eclipse has been giving me errors.

This is the method code that I have so far:

```
public void setUser(String user, Stage registerStage) throws Exception {

        String userlist = "INSERT INTO users (uid, username, email, password) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
        String overviewlist = "INSERT INTO user_overview (pid, gamertag, score, wins, goals, saves, shots, assists) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        int uid = 1;
        int pid = 1;
        double minScore = 400000.0;
        double maxScore = 10000000.0;
        int minWins = 500;
        int maxWins = 15000;
        int minGoals = 500;
        int maxGoals = 15000;
        int minSaves = 500;
        int maxSaves = 15000;
        int minShots = 500;
        int maxShots = 15000;
        int minAssists = 500;
        int maxAssists = 15000;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            // Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("Driver is Loaded");

            String strConnect = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/RLDATA";
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(strConnect,"root","");
            System.out.println("Database connected");

            PreparedStatement userstmt = connection.prepareStatement(userlist, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

            PreparedStatement overviewstmt = connection.prepareStatement(overviewlist, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

            String username = tfUsername.getText();
            String email = tfEmail.getText();
            String password = pfCPassword.getText();

            double ranScore = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(minScore, maxScore + 1);

            if (ranScore <= 1000000.0) {

            }

            userstmt.setInt(1, uid);
            userstmt.setString(2, username);
            userstmt.setString(3, email);    
            userstmt.setString(4, password);

            overviewstmt.setInt(1, pid);
            overviewstmt.setString(2, username);
            overviewstmt.setDouble(3, ranScore);
            overviewstmt.setString(2, username);
            overviewstmt.setString(2, username);
            overviewstmt.setString(2, username);
            overviewstmt.setString(2, username);
            overviewstmt.setString(2, username);

            ResultSet rs = userstmt.getGeneratedKeys();

            ResultSet rs2 = overviewstmt.getGeneratedKeys();

            if(rs.next()) {
                uid = rs.getInt(1);
            }

            if(rs2.next()) {
                pid = rs2.getInt(1);
            }

            userstmt.executeUpdate();

            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Successful Registration");
            alert.setHeaderText("Successful Registration");
            String s = "You have successfuly registered as " + user;
            alert.setContentText(s);
            alert.showAndWait();
            System.out.println("Sucess");
            registerStage.close();

        }
        catch(SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here is the database table for my project:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS RLData;
CREATE DATABASE RLData;
USE RLData;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `overview` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `uid` INT NOT NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_overview` (
  `pid` INT NOT NULL,
  `gamertag` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `score` DECIMAL(10, 1) NOT NULL,
  `wins` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `goals` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `saves` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `shots` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `assists` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pid`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `player_overview` (
  `pid` INT NOT NULL,
  `gamertag` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `score` DECIMAL(10, 1) NOT NULL,
  `wins` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `goals` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `saves` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `shots` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `assists` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pid`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO users (uid, username, email, password) VALUES
(0, 'sushhhiii', 'rocketleagueuser@gmail.com', 6543654365);

INSERT INTO user_overview (pid, gamertag, score, wins, goals, saves, shots, assists) VALUES
(0, 'sushhhiii', 2688518.2, 3032, 14811, 9918, 28633, 1920);

INSERT INTO player_overview (pid, gamertag, score, wins, goals, saves, shots, assists) VALUES
(1, 'TheCar', 3803677.6, 7744, 25550, 17305, 52249, 6777),
(2, 'Savvy', 5482247.6, 10131, 29975, 24410, 66393, 10946),
(3, 'oKhaliD', 2043555.4, 2480, 8448, 9192, 17931, 2485),
(4, 'xXander', 1631656.8, 5845, 22639, 13709, 43530, 4656),
(5, 'SML', 5372512.7, 11719, 30564, 27461, 71700, 13486),
(6, 'Killerican', 3784957.5, 9597, 42526, 26680, 82977, 8781),
(7, 'Zeldris', 832783.2, 982, 3359, 2311, 6980, 853),
(8, 'mectos', 2761034.4, 3391, 14711, 11522, 29624, 2472),
(9, 'Scrub Killa', 1053493.9, 11791, 40630, 31134, 86571, 12014),
(10, 'kuxir97', 3993712.8, 12911, 43379, 31458, 95550, 15677),
(11, 'Emre', 999486.9, 1396, 3473, 3651, 7434, 1210),
(12, 'BuZayed', 1458886.4, 2175, 7220, 4209, 14018, 1644),
(13, 'kinseh', 711179.4, 943, 4425, 2639, 7799, 367),
(14, 'King Ranny', 5991440.5, 13871, 58022, 37892, 119366, 13149),
(15, 'Brisky', 2067200.1, 2709, 7845, 5804, 17035, 2402),
(16, 'Firstkiller', 3044781.2, 6253, 19687, 20052, 43381, 7180),
(17, 'Mijo.', 4777480.5, 9107, 25237, 19222, 57470, 10461),
(18, 'Tuster', 873322.3, 1044, 4058, 2503, 8277, 890),
(19, 'eekso', 4969356.2, 7904, 31823, 21032, 62533, 7039),
(20, 'DanielAlmelo', 437627.9, 547, 1636, 1623, 3672, 472),
(21, 'Jwols', 3519406.0, 7365, 20147, 17157, 44556, 7551),
(22, 'Roll Dizz', 4865837.5, 10653, 30799, 27807, 67736, 11034),
(23, 'Oghma', 524124.3, 741, 2207, 1777, 4678, 706),
(24, 'OSM', 490561.7, 622, 2493, 1898, 4605, 462),
(25, 'Tx0', 1914821.8, 4948, 13266, 8940, 26778, 4407);

-- Create a user named mgs_user
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
ON *
TO mgs_user@localhost
IDENTIFIED BY 'pa55word';
```

Also, here is my database table with the players and their score values:

[image]

Comment: What errors is eclipse giving you? Always give us the errors or we cannot really help you.

Comment: It's mainly the user id value (uid) and player id value (pid). I'm trying to increment the value to the next when a new user is added to the database. If I try to register a second user, it gives me a duplicate error for the primary key.

Comment: Instead of trying to do the random character thing, would it be easier to just use incremental values starting at 1? you could use a DB fetch to get the highest Primary key and then increment it by 1 for the new user. Or do you have to use the random numbers as a project requirement?

Comment: It's not a project requirement, per se. It's just a value for each score property of the user that would make sense in the context of the database that I have. Also, I'm not really sure how to use a DB fetch to get the highest primary key. If you could show me that, that would be nice.

Comment: [link](https://alvinalexander.com/java/java-mysql-select-query-example) will show you how to query a DB in java, as for getting the highest ID, use a statement like this, "SELECT MAX(uid) FROM users;" that should return the highest uid value, then you could increment that by 1 and use the new value as the next users' id.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It worked for me! :)

Comment: Instead of querying the max value of a column , why not simply make the column `AUTO_INCREMENT` and let the db deal with finding an id? https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp